# How to remove bottom text in BottomTabNavigator?

Tags: react-native, react-native-ios, react-native-navigation

How do i remove the text below the icons in the bottom tab navigator?

[image]

https://snack.expo.dev/@therealsneh/justexpire---real

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Add `labeled: false` to the `MaterialBottomTabNavigatorConfig` as below:

```
...
{
  initialRouteName: 'Home',
  activeColor: 'orange',
  inactiveColor: '#aaa',
  barStyle: {
    backgroundColor: '#eee',
    borderTopLeftRadius: 20,
    borderTopRightRadius: 20,
    overflow: 'hidden',
    height: 70,
  },
  labeled: false
}
...
```

Or, see here:

https://snack.expo.dev/Zm1sZMkiL